# Switch between account sessions within one WebView

Tags: android, session, webview, android-webview, session-cookies

I would like to perform the following flow:

1. Open a webview and login to Gmail, with **account1**, and browse a bit.
2. Somehow save the current session and current url of **account1**.
3. In order to login with **account2**, I need to dispose of the session of **account1**.
4. Now to login to Gmail, with **account2**, and browse a bit.
5. Again somehow save the current session and current url of **account2**.

Now I would like to allow switching between **account1** and **account2** sessions upon user action.

Since I assume (and probably wrong) that the session is determined by the url, url params and its cookie, I've saved all for each account, and while switching I have done the following:

```
// url == url + params
CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookies();
CookieManager.getInstance().setCookie(url, cookie);
webview.loadUrl(url);
```

Which didn't work. so I've tried injecting the cookie using Javascript before loading the url, which also didn't work, by didn't work I mean that the none of the session were available, and I've returned to the Gmail login screen.

How can I do that? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
public List<Cookie>  sync(String url) {

        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        if (cookieManager == null)
            return null;

        RFC2109Spec cookieSpec = new RFC2109Spec();
        String rawCookieHeader = null;
        try {
            URL parsedURL = new URL(url);
            rawCookieHeader = cookieManager.getCookie(parsedURL.getHost());
            if (rawCookieHeader == null)
                return null;
            int port = parsedURL.getPort() == -1 ? parsedURL.getDefaultPort() : parsedURL.getPort();

            CookieOrigin cookieOrigin = new CookieOrigin(parsedURL.getHost(), port, "/", false);
            List<Cookie> cookies = cookieSpec.parse(new BasicHeader("set-cookie", rawCookieHeader), cookieOrigin);
            return cookies;
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return null;
    }


    public void sync(List<Cookie> cookies,String url) {
        if (cookies != null) {

            CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
            cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
            for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {

                Cookie sessionInfo = cookie;
                String cookieString = sessionInfo.getName() + "=" + sessionInfo.getValue() + "; domain=" + sessionInfo.getDomain();
                cookieManager.setCookie(url, cookieString);
                CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
            }
        }
    }
```

**HOw to use**

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
                sync(url); // store list of cookies in Global variable return by this function. 
            }
        });

        //before loading/swithich account

        //sync(yourglobalvariable of list of cookis, url of respective account);
        sync(cookies,urlAccount1);
        webview.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: Looks interesting... I'll give it a go in the next couple of days. were you able to get this sort of thing to work?

Comment: In my case was authenticate/login through webview and return to my native application and using same session that was created by webview , I need to use in webservice(Http) call. So This solution was works for me. I was using list of cookies generated by webview with my "HttpClient" and it works like charm.

Comment: Sound promising... I'll test this during the weekend, thanks.

Comment: I didn't get to test it yet, but just for the effort :)